# How to print matlab struct into a text file?

Tags: matlab

I am an R user: I don't use Matlab. However, I am working with a genomic file from the Broad Institute called "hg18_with_miR_20080407.mat". You can find it at: http://genepattern.broadinstitute.org/ftp/distribution/genepattern/dev_archive/GISTIC/broad.mit.edu:cancer.software.genepattern.module.analysis/00125/1.1/

I tried to use the R package R.matlab (table <- readMat("~/desktop/hg18_with_miR_20080407.mat")), but it keeps loading in definitively. Hence, since I need that file today, I used a friend's computer with Matlab. I have a struct <1x26835> called rg
Each variable has the following values:

```
refseq        'NM_003585'
gene          'double C2...'
symb          'DOC2B'
locus_id      8447
...
```

Is there a way that I can print each entry into a text file that I could easily parse? Is there a better way? I am reading the Matlab documentation but would appreciate if someone could give me a one-liner. If not possible, how could I search each variable for a specific gene entry? I keep getting errors. For example:

```
 find(rg == 'Met')
 Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying YAML files ([site](http://www.yaml.org/)).

There are libraries for writing matlab data into it [here](https://code.google.com/p/yamlmatlab/) that I have used and liked and googling shows me that there appear to be libraries for R as well.

YAML is basically a newer version of XML files that is human readable, simpler, and less extensible.

Comment: Regarding the specific error you encountered, that is probably happening because you cannot run `find` on a struct.